# How to move scroll view up 100 pixels when button is clicked

Tags: android

I have a scrollview and need to move 100 DP up when button click event is happening.

I'm using scrollTo (0,1) but not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTo(0,1)` will bring you to height 1 of the `ScrollView` layout.

As far as I know, you cannot scrollTo using arbitrary amount of pixels in ScrollView (pls correct me if I'm wrong).

You could try having a `View` inside the `ScrollView` as a "guide" for your `ScrollView` where does it need to stop.

Example:

```
//inside your button onClick
yourScrollView.scrollTo(0, someView.getBottom());
```

This will make your `ScrollView` scrolls to the bottom of a `View` that you can put 100dp above.

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Hope it will work

```
it px = (int) (100 * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density)
yourScrollView.scrollTo(0, px);
```